# Stored procedure returns null as output parameter

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have `stored procedure`, which works great in MS SQL management studio.

When I try to use it in VS rows returns fine, but value of output parameters is **NULL**.

```c#
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_name", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p_SomeVal", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters["@p_SomeVal"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
//...process rows...

if (cmd.Parameters["@p_SomeVal"].Value != null)
SomeVal = (int)cmd.Parameters["@p_SomeVal"].Value;
```

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); Has the same result.

```
USE [db_name]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
    @p_SomeValue int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Proc_name]
    @p_InputVal = N'aa',
    @p_SomeValue = @p_SomeValue OUTPUT

SELECT  @p_SomeValue as N'p_SomeValue'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: What's the procedure look like? Are you running it in the same database in VS and in SSMS?

Comment: @Oded yes DB is the same. And parameters is the same.

Comment: By the way you should be testing against `DBNull.Value`, not `null`.

Comment: @Oded Tried that too with the same luck

Comment: Check your connection strings again. I suspect you are on **different** databases (possibly on the same server)

Comment: If you are indeed running the query on the same database, the only reason you would get different results for the same set of inputs, is if one of the sessions is in an uncommitted transaction.

Comment: @Oded yes connection string is the same - rows returned by this procedure is the same as well - only output paramaters is null

Comment: Without seeing the stored procedure definition, it isn't possible to help further.

Comment: @Oded I added what I have about this proc - i do not have rights to see more

Comment: I can't make sense of what you have there - it looks like you are just forwarding parameters around - and still can't see what `Proc_name` looks like.

Comment: @Oded it is that SSMS gives me in SQL pane then I execute procedure.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_name", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p_SomeVal", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters["@p_SomeVal"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
//...process rows...

rdr.Close();

if (cmd.Parameters["@p_SomeVal"].Value != null)
SomeVal = (int)cmd.Parameters["@p_SomeVal"].Value;
```

After procesing rows I added `rdr.Close();` and worked fine.

Comment: @Oded solution was simple :(

Comment: Or if you like one-liners you could do something like var SomeVal = command.Parameters["@p_SomeVal"].Value != null ? (int)command.Parameters["@p_SomeVal"].Value : default(int);

Comment: Sorry I was too hasty... null and DBNull... you will have to use this here                         var SomeVal = command.Parameters["@p_SomeVal"].Value is DBNull ? default(int) : (int)command.Parameters["@p_SomeVal"].Value;

Answer (score 3):

Salaam,
You can check if output is null and convert like this.

```
returnedSQLParameter.Value != DBNull.Value? (int)returnedSQLParameter.Value : 0;
```

Because it is returning `DBNull.value` when output sent `NULL` from stored procedure.